# Shopify Facebook like&share counter for products

Tags: facebook, shopify

Why it doesn't show counter when the var permalink = {{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }} , but it show when insert url ..example: var permalink = google.com

```
{% capture permalinkURL %}{{ shop.url }}{{ product.url }}{% endcapture %}  

<a href="{{ permalinkURL }}" >Facebook<span class="share-count"></span>      </a>  

<script>

var permalink = '{{ permalinkURL }}';

var getFacebookCount = function () {
  $.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids='+permalink+'&callback=?';, function(data){
    var facebookShares = data[permalink].shares;
    $('.facebook .share-count').text(facebookShares);
  });
};

getFacebookCount(); 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be missing part of the Facebook code in the anchor. Try this.

```
<a href="//www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={{ permalinkURL }}">Facebook<span class="share-count">0</span></a>
```